# Does msvcrt.dll use a linear congruential generator for its rand() function?

Tags: c++, random, msvcrt, dice

I am trying to predict the output of a program that uses msvcrt's rand() function for generating the face of three dice. I believe the code is something like:
`dice[0] = rand() % 6 + 1; dice[1] = rand() % 6 + 1; dice[2] = rand() % 6 + 1;`, and I was wondering if I could use a prediction program for linear congruential generators to predict the next numbers in the sequence.

Comment: You could dump the relevant bit of the DLL and look at the generator code yourself.

Comment: Why? You have access to the source code -- it's two lines.

Comment: I should dig through that stuff more often. I didn't even realize it was there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See for yourself: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\crt\src\rand.c`

(Or use `%VCINSTALLDIR%\crt\src\rand.c` if you're running from a VC command prompt.)

(Assuming you have *at least the standard version* of VC. It's two lines. I'd post it, but not sure whether the license allows it.)

Comment: %VCINSTALLDIR%\crt\src\rand.c is more general.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed. I went through all this just to find that the program I am trying to predict doesn't work as I predicted (it calls rand() in various other parts of the program, screwing up my seed).

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, yes it's a linear congruential generator -- but what it returns is the remainder of a larger output, which increases the difficulty of predicting the next number (to the point that you probably need a much larger sample than three outputs to do so dependably).