# Executable runs faster on Wine than Windows -- why?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, performance, benchmarking

**Solution:** Apparently the culprit was the use of `floor()`, the performance of which turns out to be OS-dependent in glibc.

---

This is a followup question to an earlier one: [Same program faster on Linux than Windows -- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071851/same-program-faster-on-linux-than-windows-why)

**I have a small C++ program, that, when compiled with [nuwen gcc 4.6.1](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html), runs much faster on Wine than Windows XP (on the same computer).  The question: why does this happen?**

The timings are ~15.8 and 25.9 seconds, for Wine and Windows respectively.  Note that I'm talking about the same *executable*, not only the same C++ program.

The source code is at the end of the post.  The compiled executable is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38623/test2-gcc.exe) (if you trust me enough).

This particular program does nothing useful, it is just a minimal example boiled down from a larger program I have.  Please see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071851/same-program-faster-on-linux-than-windows-why) for some more precise benchmarking of the original program (important!!) and the most common possibilities ruled out (such as other programs hogging the CPU on Windows, process startup penalty, difference in system calls such as memory allocation).  Also note that while here I used `rand()` for simplicity, in the original I used my own RNG which I know does no heap-allocation.

*The reason I opened a new question on the topic is that now I can post an actual simplified code example for reproducing the phenomenon.*

**The code:**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>


int irand(int top) {
    return int(std::floor((std::rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)) * top));
}

template<typename T>
class Vector {
    T *vec;
    const int sz;

public:
    Vector(int n) : sz(n) {
        vec = new T[sz];
    }

    ~Vector() {
        delete [] vec;
    }

    int size() const { return sz; }

    const T & operator [] (int i) const { return vec[i]; }
    T & operator [] (int i) { return vec[i]; }
};


int main() {
    const int tmax = 20000; // increase this to make it run longer
    const int m = 10000;
    Vector<int> vec(150);

    for (int i=0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        vec[i] = 0;

    // main loop
    for (int t=0; t < tmax; ++t)
        for (int j=0; j < m; ++j) {
            int s = irand(100) + 1;
            vec[s] += 1;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that if I replace `irand()` above with something deterministic such as

```
int irand(int top) {
    static int c = 0;
    return (c++) % top;
}
```

then the timing difference disappears.  I'd like to note though that in [my original program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071851/same-program-faster-on-linux-than-windows-why) I used a different RNG, not the system `rand()`.  I'm digging into the source of that now.

**UPDATE 2**

Now I replaced the `irand()` function with an equivalent of what I had in the original program.  It is a bit lengthy (the algorithm is from [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/)), but the point was to show that no system libraries are being called explictly (except possibly through `floor()`).  Yet the timing difference is still there!

Perhaps `floor()` could be to blame?  Or the compiler generates calls to something else?

```
class ran1 {
    static const int table_len = 32;
    static const int int_max = (1u << 31) - 1;

    int idum;
    int next;
    int *shuffle_table;

    void propagate() {
        const int int_quo = 1277731;

        int k = idum/int_quo;
        idum = 16807*(idum - k*int_quo) - 2836*k;
        if (idum < 0)
            idum += int_max;
    }

public:
    ran1() {
        shuffle_table = new int[table_len];
        seedrand(54321);
    }
    ~ran1() {
        delete [] shuffle_table;
    }

    void seedrand(int seed) {
        idum = seed;
        for (int i = table_len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            propagate();
            shuffle_table[i] = idum;
        }
        next = idum;
    }

    double frand() {
        int i = next/(1 + (int_max-1)/table_len);
        next = shuffle_table[i];
        propagate();
        shuffle_table[i] = idum;
        return next/(int_max + 1.0);
    }
} rng;


int irand(int top) {
    return int(std::floor(rng.frand() * top));
}
```

Comment: linked statically/dynamically (what dll dependencies?)

Comment: @sehe I have a 32-bit CPU, both are 32-bit OSs

Comment: Could you eliminate the calls to `std::floor()` and `std::rand()`, e.g. by replacing `irand()` with a function that would return the same deterministic pattern? It would be interesting to see whether the difference in performance persists.

Comment: because Windows is shit.. Linux gogogo! woohooo!...... :)

Comment: Also, just to be clear, you're running Windows on bare metal, and not inside a virtual machine of any kind, correct?

Comment: do you have an antivirus on your windows box that you don't have on your wine box ? I experienced the same results for programms that was relying on network and file access, and without antivirus, performance were much more similar.

Comment: @aix I'm running both normally, no virtual machines.  It's a dual boot system, so it's going to take a while to test again after replacing irand.  But yes, that's the next logical step, I just got tired of all the rebooting :-)

Comment: @CédricJulien I have an antivirus, but I disabled real-time protection.  Also, MSVC-compiled executables don't show this difference, only mingw-compiled ones.

Comment: @aix Good point, if I replace `irand` by `int irand(int top) { static int c=0; return (c++) % top; }`, the timing difference disappears (or becomes quite small).  The strange thing is that in my original program I was using the RNG from Numerical Recipes, not the systen `rand()`.  I'm digging into the RNG now.

Comment: With optimizations and static linking, and `tmax = 2000`, I get 3.3 seconds on Windows XP on a 2GHz Pentium M, and 2.2 seconds on Linux on a 1.2GHz Core Duo (natively compiled)...

Comment: What happens if you remove `std::floor` as well? Conversion to int should implicitly truncate the value anyway.

Comment: @celtschk It turns out the difference was due to `floor()`!  I never thought that `floor()` could be OS-dependent, but apparently in glibc it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**edit: It turned out that the culprit was `floor()` and not `rand()` as I suspected - see 
 the update at the top of the OP's question.**

The run time of your program is dominated by the calls to `rand()`.

I therefore think that `rand()` is the culprit. I suspect that the underlying function is provided by the WINE/Windows runtime, and the two implementations have different performance characteristics.

The easiest way to test this hypothesis would be to simply call `rand()` in a loop, and time the same executable in both environments.

**edit** I've had a look at the WINE source code, and here is its implementation of `rand()`:

```
/*********************************************************************
 *              rand (MSVCRT.@)
 */
int CDECL MSVCRT_rand(void)
{
    thread_data_t *data = msvcrt_get_thread_data();

    /* this is the algorithm used by MSVC, according to
     * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pseudorandom_number_generators */
    data->random_seed = data->random_seed * 214013 + 2531011;
    return (data->random_seed >> 16) & MSVCRT_RAND_MAX;
}
```

I don't have access to [Microsoft's source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931656/does-msvcrt-dll-use-a-linear-congruential-generator-for-its-rand-function/1931677#1931677) to compare, but it wouldn't surprise me if the difference in performance was in the getting of thread-local data rather than in the RNG itself.

Comment: Even if rand runs the same speed, if it returns different results, it might affect timing, as the results are used for indexing and therefore can affect caching efficiency.

Comment: @Suma: Indeed. However, since the array is only 150 ints long, I suspect it's the actual call that's 2x faster in WINE than in Windows. However, neither possibility can be ruled out at the point.

Comment: @Suma That's a good point in general, but I doubt it's the case here.  The array (150 ints) should fit in the cache, and any non-totally-broken rand() should result in the same (average) access pattern.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to  check the disassembly to see if std::rand really calls some WinAPI function? I would expect it to be a runtime function, not OS function. (The results seem to indicate it is a OS call, but it might be interesting to verify)

Comment: @Suma: It definitely is. It's part of the Visual C runtime, which WINE has to emulate (see my updated answer).

Comment: @Suma I swapped `irand()` for my own RNG (see update 2 in the question), but the difference is still there.  I'm looking at `floor` now and will also look at the assembly output.

Comment: @Szabolcs: The `floor()` call should be easy to eliminate from the inquiry, since invoking it just before calling `int()` with a non-negative argument appears entirely redundant.

Comment: @aix It turns out the culprit was indeed `floor()`.  Thanks for all the suggestions :-)

Comment: I still find it a bit strange that such a fundamental operation as `floor()` is not implemented in glibc directly, but it relies on the OS instead.  I'd hope that a good compiler would inline such functions (together with `sin`, `cos`, etc.)

Comment: @Szabolcs: I too find it odd.

Comment: Can you share details how is the floor function implemented?

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia says:

> Wine is a compatibility layer not an emulator. It duplicates functions
>   of a Windows computer by providing alternative implementations of the
>   DLLs that Windows programs call,[citation needed] and a process to
>   substitute for the Windows NT kernel. This method of duplication
>   differs from other methods that might also be considered emulation,
>   where Windows programs run in a virtual machine.[2] Wine is
>   predominantly written using black-box testing reverse-engineering, to
>   avoid copyright issues.

This implies that the developers of wine could replace an api call with anything at all to as long as the end result was the same as you would get with a native windows call.  And I suppose they weren't constrained by needing to make it compatible with the rest of Windows.

Comment: Yes, but do you have a hypothesis for how the Windows API even enters the picture in this case?

Comment: My point is that those APIs are not being called.  I don't see how the main loop of the program could make any system calls.

Comment: You should inspect memory image of the executed program, to see that certain calls are optimized (BY OS) only when running code compiled with VS, so GCC has old slow implementation, unless of course you run it with wine wich does not emulate such behaviour. (speculations :P)

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, the C standard libraries used WILL be different in the two different scenarios.  This affects the rand() call as well as floor().

From the mingw site... `MinGW compilers provide access to the functionality of the Microsoft C runtime and some language-specific runtimes.`  Running under XP, this will use the Microsoft libraries.  Seems straightforward.

However, the model under wine is much more complex.  According to [this diagram](http://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/x2550), the operating system's libc comes into play.  This could be the difference between the two.

Answer (score -1):

While Wine is basically Windows, you're still comparing apples to oranges. As well, not only is it apples/oranges, the underlying vehicles hauling those apples and oranges around are completely different.

In short, your question could trivially be rephrased as "this code runs faster on Mac OSX than it does on Windows" and get the same answer.

Comment: Why would there be a difference if the code does not use system libraries?  If it's the same code being run on the same CPU, it should take the same time.  It's not clear to me why it wouldn't.

Comment: @Szabolcs: why ask, if we can't profile on your machine? You should simply run it under gprof on both ends. Or simply start out with a `strace -c` on linux.